# SSIS does not recognize Indexes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssis, dataflow

I have a table with a non-Clustered index on a varchar column 'A'.
when I use **Order By A** clause I can see it scans the index and gives me the result in a few seconds.
But when I use **Sort Component** of SSIS for column 'A', I can see it takes minutes to sort records.

---

So I understand that it does not recognize my non-clustered index

---

Does anyone has any idea for using indexes for SSIS but not using queries instead of components??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I researched and working with SSIS these times I found out that the only way to use indexes is to connnect to database. However, when you fetch your data in the flow, all you have are just records and data. no indexes!

---

So for tasks like `Merge Join` which needs a `Sort component` before that, I tried to use `Lookup` component instead with **full cache** option. and cache whole data then use `ORDER BY` in the `Source component` **query**

Answer (score 5):

`Order By A` is run in the database.

When using a sort component, the sort is done in the SSIS runtime. Note that the query you use to feed to the sort does not have an order by in it (I assume)

It's done in the runtime because it is data source agnostic - your source could be excel or a text file or an in memory dataset or a multicase or pivot or anything.

My advice is to use the database as much as possible.

The only reason to use a sort in a SSIS package is if your source doesn't support sorting (i.e. a flat file) and you want to do a merge join in your package to something else. Which is a very rare and specific case

Comment: Also when my sorted data passes from some components, merge join doesnt recognize it is sorted any more. So this is another reason to use sort. right? any other solutions for that?

Comment: You need to manually set the IsSorted property. You, the developer, are the only one that knows it's sorted. (Unless it just came straight out of a sorted component). If you are extensively using the sort component, you're going to run into performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

[31 Days of SSIS – What The Sorts](https://jasonstrate.com/2011/01/07/31-days-of-ssis-what-the-sorts-731/):

> Whether there are one hundred rows or ten million rows – **all of the rows have to be consumed by the Sort Transformation before it can return the first row.**    This potentially places all of the data for the data flow path in memory.  And the potentially bit is because if there is enough data it will spill over out of memory.
>
> In the image to the right you can see that until the ten million rows are all received that data after that point in the Data Flow cannot be processed.
>
> This behavior should be expected if you consider what the transformation needs to do.  Before the first row can be sent along, the last row needs to be checked to make sure that it is not the first row.
>
> **For small and narrow datasets, this is not an issue.  But if you’re dataset are large or wide you can find performance issues with packages that have sorts within them.  All of the data load and sorted in memory can be a serious performance hog**